# How can I find the current base class in a classmethod invoked by super?

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, oop, inheritance, super

How can I find the current base class in a classmethod invoked by super?

- Class B inherits from A
- The code in both data methods must be the same and should not include a literal class reference like A or B

I want the method data to gather the _data values going up the base classes.

```
class A:
  _data = "A data"
  @classmethod
  def data(cls) -> list[str]:
    # gather data here too, we may have N number of inheritance classes so we should try to invoke super here too

class B(A):
  _data = "B data"
  @classmethod
  def data(cls) -> list[str]:
    # gather data here and invoke super to gather data from A also
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can get the current base class with `super().__thisclass__`
Using this solution we can write the below code which meets these requirements:

- Class B inherits from A
- The code in both data methods must be the same and should not include a literal class reference like A or B

```
class A:
    _data = "A data"
    @classmethod
    def data(cls):
        super_instance = super()
        this_cls = super_instance.__thisclass__
        try:
            other_data = super_instance.data()
        except AttributeError:
            return [this_cls._data]
        return [this_cls._data] + other_data

class B(A):
    _data = "B data"
    @classmethod
    def data(cls):
        super_instance = super()
        this_cls = super_instance.__thisclass__
        try:
            other_data = super_instance.data()
        except AttributeError:
            return [this_cls._data]
        return [this_cls._data] + other_data

B.data()
# ['B data', 'A data']
```

Or one can refactor that into the shorter:

```
class DataGatherer:
    @staticmethod
    def gather_data(super_instance):
        this_cls = super_instance.__thisclass__
        try:
            other_data = super_instance.data()
        except AttributeError:
            return [this_cls._data]
        return [this_cls._data] + other_data


class A(DataGatherer):
    _data = "A data"
    @classmethod
    def data(cls):
        return cls.gather_data(super())

class B(A):
    _data = "B data"
    @classmethod
    def data(cls):
        return cls.gather_data(super())
```